# appending array of arrays to FormData and send via AJAX

Tags: javascript, laravel, form-data

I need to send an array of arrays in a multipart form.

```js
let currentObj = this;
let formData = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < this.mediaData.length; i++) {
  let file = this.mediaData[i];
  console.log(file, "file");
  formData.append('medias[' + i + ']', , file.file, file.original_file_name, file.function_name);
}
for (var i = 0; i < this.mud_table.name.length; i++) {
  let mud = this.mud_table.name[i];
  formData.append('mud_table[' + i + ']', mud);
}
formData.append('mud_map_status', this.mud.status);
formData.append('mud_map_id', this.mud.id)
formData.append('surveyReportID', this.survey_reporting_id);
```

with this code i can only send the files file property from the mediasData array into a controller.

```
mediasData:[function_name:mud_pdf1; original_file_name: recipt_pdf.pdf; file:{File},
function_name:mud_pdf2; original_file_name: recipt_pdf.pdf; file:{File},
function_name:mud_pdf3; original_file_name: recipt_pdf.pdf; file:{File}]
```

is in this format and in the backend I am only getting `medias:[file:{File}]` format in the request.
i also need to send the "original_file_name" and "function_name" properties too. of course i could break the array into 3 parts and append them individually, but is there any way to send all there properties of each mediasData array index into formdata array respective index?

Comment: I'm not seeing any nested arrays here. Also, your `mediasNames` bit looks very odd. Could you please explain what data you want to send?

Comment: mideasName was my cheating way to actually post the function_name array to the controller. but i need to append it to the mideas variable too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormData` allows you to specify a *filename* when [appending files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#Syntax) so that should take care of your `original_file_name` property.

```js
formData.append(`medias[${i}]`, file.file, file.original_file_name)
```

This can be read by PHP in `$_FILES['medias']['name'][$index]` or whatever the relevant Laravel abstraction is. I'm sure it supports file name.

As for your other fields, your only real option is to add a new array with corresponding indexes. You appear to have been attempting to do this with `mediasNames` but it should look more like

```js
formData.append(`mediaFunctionNames[${i}]`, file.function_name)
```

---

To summarise

```js
let formData = new FormData();
this.mediaData.forEach((file, i) => {
  formData.append(`medias[${i}]`, file.file, file.original_file_name)
  formData.append(`mediaFunctionNames[${i}]`, file.function_name)
})
this.mud_table.name.forEach((mud, i) => {
  formData.append(`mud_table[${i}]`, mud)
})
```

Comment: thank you for sharing this information @phil . it seems i have no option to somehow merge these arrays in backend instead trying to send them all at once. And i forgot to mention that i have been using vue.js for this.